# Is there a noun that means "Scared of being made fun of"?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I am looking for a noun that is a synonym for "scared of being made fun of".

Comment: Would you give an example sentence to show how you would like to use this noun please? Sometimes that makes it easier to find the right word.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you are you looking for a noun, and not an adjective?

Comment: They are not direct synonyms, but *shy*, *timid*, and *apprehensive* might work for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The only phrase that I can come up with other than "social anxiety", which Peter has already mentioned, is "fear of humiliation".

> In her book Fear and Other Uninvited Guests, psychologist Harriet Lerner points out that of all the forces that shape human behavior, **fear of humiliation** is among the most powerful. The most common fear is not of illness or accident, but public speaking; soldiers will march into certain doom rather than be branded cowards. 
>   [*(Source)*](http://www.oprah.com/spirit/Martha-Beck-Shame-Embarrassment-Humiliation)